# Scala -- List into List of Count and List of Element

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Let's say I have Scala list like this:

```
val mylist = List(4,2,5,6,4,4,2,6,5,6,6,2,5,4,4)
```

How can I transform it into list of count and list of element? For example, I want to convert `mylist` into:

```
val count = List(3,5,3,4)
val elements = List(2,4,5,6)
```

Which means, in `mylist`, I have three occurrences of 2, five occurrences of 4, etc.

In procedural, this is easy as I can just make two empty lists (for count and elements) and fill them while doing iteration. However, I have no idea on how to achieve this in Scala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arguably a shortest version:

```
 val elements = mylist.distinct
 val count = elements map (e => mylist.count(_ == e))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `.groupBy(identity)` to create a `Map` regrouping elements with their occurences:

```
scala> val mylist = List(4,2,5,6,4,4,2,6,5,6,6,2,5,4,4)
mylist: List[Int] = List(4, 2, 5, 6, 4, 4, 2, 6, 5, 6, 6, 2, 5, 4, 4)

scala> mylist.groupBy(identity)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(2 -> List(2, 2, 2), 5 -> List(5, 5, 5), 4 -> List(4, 4, 4, 4, 4), 6 -> List(6, 6, 6, 6))
```

---

Then you can use `.mapValues(_.length)` to change the 'value' part of the map to the size of the list:

```
scala> mylist.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(2 -> 3, 5 -> 3, 4 -> 5, 6 -> 4)
```

---

If you want to get 2 lists out of this you can use `.unzip`, which returns a tuple, the first part being the keys (ie the elements), the second being the values (ie the number of instances of the element in the original list):

```
scala> val (elements, counts) = mylist.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length).unzip
elements: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] = List(2, 5, 4, 6)
counts: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] = List(3, 3, 5, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use `groupBy` and then check the size of each "group":

```
val withSizes = mylist.groupBy(identity).toList.map { case (v, l) => (v, l.size) }
val count = withSizes.map(_._2)
val elements = withSizes.map(_._1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this as well alternative way of doing the same.

**Step - 1**

scala> val mylist = List(4,2,5,6,4,4,2,6,5,6,6,2,5,4,4)

mylist: List[Int] = List(4, 2, 5, 6, 4, 4, 2, 6, 5, 6, 6, 2, 5, 4, 4)

// Use groupBy { x => x } returns a "Map[Int, List[Int]]"

**step - 2**

scala> mylist.groupBy(x => (x))

res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(2 -> List(2, 2, 2), 5 -> List(5, 5, 5), 4 -> List(4, 4, 4, 4, 4), 6 -> List(6, 6, 6, 6))

**step - 3**

scala> mylist.groupBy(x => (x)).map{case(num,times) =>(num,times.size)}.toList

res1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,3), (5,3), (4,5), (6,4))

**step -4** - sort by num

scala> mylist.groupBy(x => (x)).map{case(num,times) =>(num,times.size)}.toList.sortBy(_._1)

res2: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,3), (4,5), (5,3), (6,4))

**step -5** - unzip to beak into to list it return tuple

scala> mylist.groupBy(x => (x)).map{case(num,times) =>(num,times.size)}.toList.sortBy(_._1).unzip
res3: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(2, 4, 5, 6),List(3, 5, 3, 4))